# Whats the most elegant way to transform this JSON structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

How to transform the following data with few lines of code?

From:

```js
[
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"left"},
  {filter:true, type:"two", name:"up"},
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"right"},
  {filter:false, type:"three", name:"down"}
]
```

Into:

```
[
  ["left","right"],
  ["up"]
]
```

The transformation do the following:

1. keep items where `filter` is `true`
2. group items by `type`
3. map items on their `name` value

Performance does not matter, only cognitive complexity does.

Today, I use lodash filter/group then a double loop to map items in the sub-arrays.

I am curious to see it exists a way to do the same job without a double loop.

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes simple is cleaner. Create an object where type is the key and then grab the values:

```js
var arr = [{filter:true, type:"one", name:"left"}, {filter:true, type:"two", name:"up"}, {filter:true, type:"one", name:"right"}, {filter:false, type:"three", name:"down"}];

var obj = {};
arr.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.filter){
    obj[item.type] = obj[item.type] || [];
    obj[item.type].push(item.name);
  }
});
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Or, if you're willing to sacrifice readability for shortness:

```js
var arr = [{filter:true, type:"one", name:"left"}, {filter:true, type:"two", name:"up"}, {filter:true, type:"one", name:"right"}, {filter:false, type:"three", name:"down"}];

var obj = {};
arr.forEach((item) => {if(item.filter) obj[item.type] ? obj[item.type].push(item.name) : obj[item.type] = [item.name];});
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Answer (score 3):

1. [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for `filter` and check for True
2. [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), to create our Object; using `type` for the Key, and build an Array of `name` as the Value
3. [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to return only the Values of that Object

```js
const data = [
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"left"},
  {filter:true, type:"two", name:"up"},
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"right"},
  {filter:false, type:"three", name:"down"}
];

const newArray = Object.values(data
  .filter(({filter}) => filter)
  .reduce((acc, {type, name}) => {
    acc[type] = acc[type] || [];
    acc[type].push(name);
    return acc;
  }, {})
);
  
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce to iterate the array, and group the names in an object by their type, and then convert the object back to an array with `Object.values()`:

```js
const arr = [{"filter":true,"type":"one","name":"left"},{"filter":true,"type":"two","name":"up"},{"filter":true,"type":"one","name":"right"},{"filter":false,"type":"three","name":"down"}]

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((r, o) => {
    if(!o.filter) return r // ignore item if filter is false
    
    if(!r[o.type]) r[o.type] = [] // init a property in the accumulator by the type, if none exists
    
    r[o.type].push(o.name) // push the current name to the type property in the accumulator

    return r
  }, {})
)

console.log(result)
```

Another approach would be to filter out items with `filter: false`, and then reduce to a Map. Afterwards you can convert the Map back to an object by using `Array.from()` on the Map's `.values()` iterator:

```js
const arr = [{"filter":true,"type":"one","name":"left"},{"filter":true,"type":"two","name":"up"},{"filter":true,"type":"one","name":"right"},{"filter":false,"type":"three","name":"down"}]

const result = Array.from(arr
  .filter(o => o.filter) // remove items with filter: false
  .reduce((r, o) =>
    r.set(o.type, [...(r.get(o.type) || []), o.name]) // reduce to a Map
  , new Map()
).values()) // get an array from the Map's values

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
var data = [{ filter: true, type: "one", name: "left" }, { filter: true, type: "two", name: "up" }, { filter: true, type: "one", name: "right" }, { filter: false, type: "three", name: "down" }],
    result = Array.from(data
        .reduce(
            (m, { filter, type, name }) => filter
                ? m.set(type, [...(m.get(type) || []), name])
                : m,
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const arr = [
  { filter: true, type: "one", name: "left" },
  { filter: true, type: "two", name: "up" },
  { filter: true, type: "one", name: "right" },
  { filter: false, type: "three", name: "down" }
];

const groupItems = arr => {
    const dict = {};
    arr.forEach(item => {
        const {type, name, filter} = item;
        if (filter) {
            dict[type] ? dict[type].push(name) : dict[type] = [name];
        }
    });
    return Object.values(dict);
}

console.log(groupItems(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"left"},
  {filter:true, type:"two", name:"up"},
  {filter:true, type:"one", name:"right"},
  {filter:false, type:"three", name:"down"}
]

const output = arr
  .filter(item => item.filter)
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const existing_item = acc.find(item => item.type === curr.type);
    if (!existing_item) {
      acc.push({ ...curr, names: [curr.name] });
    } else {
      existing_item.names.push(curr.name);
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .map(obj => obj.names);

console.log({output});


// Alternate way

const output2 = Object.values(
  arr
    .filter(item => item.filter)
    .reduce(
      (acc, curr) => ({
        ...acc,
        [curr.type]:
          curr.type in acc ? [...acc[curr.type], curr.name] : [curr.name]
      }),
      {}
    )
);

console.log({ output2 });
```